# MySQL - return one row from 2 rows in the same table, overwrite the contents of the first 'default' with the populated fields of the second 'override'

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I am trying to make use of the mobile device lookup data in the WUFL database at http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/smart.php but I'm having problems getting my head around the MySQL code needed (I use Coldfusion for the server backend). To be honest its really doing my head in but I'm sure there is a straightforward approach to this.

The WUFL is supplied as XML (approx 15200 records to date), I have the method written that saves the data to a MySQL database already. Now I need to get the data back out in a useful way!

Basically it works like this: firstly run a select using the **userAgent** data from a CGI pull to match against a known mobile device (row 1) using LIKE; if found then use the resultant **fallback** field to look up the default data for the mobile device's 'family root' (row 2). The two rows need to be combined by overwriting the contents of (row 2) with the specific mobile device's features of (row 1). Both rows contain NULL entries and not all the features are present in (row 1).

I just need the fully populated row of data returned if a match is found. I hope that makes sense, I would provide what I think the SQL should look like but I will probably confuse things even more.

Really appreciate any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my shot at it in SQL Server. You would need to use [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) instead of `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(row1.Feature1, row2.Feature1) AS Feature 1
    , ISNULL(row1.Feature2, row2.Feature2) AS Feature 2
    , ISNULL(row1.Feature3, row2.Feature3) AS Feature 3
FROM
    featureTable row1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN featureTable row2 ON row1.fallback = row2.familyroot
WHERE row1.userAgent LIKE '%Some User Agent String%'
```

This should accomplish the same thing in MySQL:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(row1.Feature1, row2.Feature1) AS Feature 1
    , IFNULL(row1.Feature2, row2.Feature2) AS Feature 2
    , IFNULL(row1.Feature3, row2.Feature3) AS Feature 3
FROM
    featureTable AS row1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN featureTable AS row2 ON row1.fallback = row2.familyroot
WHERE row1.userAgent LIKE '%Some User Agent String%'
```

So what this does, is takes your feature table, aliases it as row1 to get your specific model features. We then join it back to itself as row2 to get the family features. Then the `ISNULL` function says "if there is no Feature1 value in row 1 (it's null) then get the Feature1 value from row2".

Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks good as a starting point, cheers! It will need modifiying though unfortunately. There are literally about 50 old fields which would make the SQL huge and inelegant plus the 'family' features are not always NULL but still need overwriting with the 'model' updates. Sorry I should have made that clearer!

Comment: Well it sounds like you ave multiple different cases around how values from row2 should be overwritten by row1. You'll most likely end up having to write CASE statements for each field to suit their individual requirements. Without more detail, you won't get any clearer answers :)

Comment: I knew this wasn't going to be straight forward :) Effectively if a field has data in row1 it needs to overwrite the corresponding field of row2 before returning. Can * be used to do this in one hit??

Comment: The `IFNULL` function doesn't support *, so I don't think this is something where you can just type 10 characters and have it done :). Besides, any time you press `Shift+8` a puppy dies...